# Wrong hidden field value submitted

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form of checkboxes with a hidden_field attached to each checkbox.

And whenever the user submits the form, the value for the last hidden_field is always submitted. why?

```
  <%= search_form_for @q, id: "filters_click", remote: true do |f| %>
    <div id="dates">
      <% i = 1 %>
      <% @weeks.each do |date| %>
        <div class="ck-button ">
          <label class="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center">
              <%= hidden_field_tag :start_dt_lteq, (date.to_date + 7.days), input_html: { name: 'week-#{i}' } %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :start_dt_gteq, date, nil, class: "date" %>
            <span class="align-self-center">
                  Week <br />
              <%= i %>
              <% i += 1 %>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**UPDATE: In reponse to comments I get the following results after clicking a checkbox:**

Suggested edit:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'start_dt_lteq[]', (date.to_date + 7.days), input_html: { name: 'week-#{i}' } %>
```

Result:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "start_dt_lteq"=>["2018-04-02", "2018-04-09", "2018-04-16", "2018-04-23", "2018-04-30", "2018-05-07", "2018-05-14", "2018-05-21", "2018-05-28", "2018-06-04", "2018-06-11", "2018-06-18"], "q"=>{"start_dt_gteq"=>["2018-04-23"]}}
```

What it SHOULD BE:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "start_dt_lteq"=>["2018-04-30"], "q"=>{"start_dt_gteq"=>["2018-04-23"]}}
```

Comment: Perhaps because there's only one `start_dt_lteq`, and no matter how many times you iterate, Rails uses always the last one defined. Maybe you want to add some identifier to differentiate them.

Comment: They're all being submitted but Rails thinks that parameters named `start_dt_lteq` should only have a single value so it only puts the last one into `params`. A parameter named `start_dt_lteq[]` OTOH...

Comment: Updated my question to reflect the results of using `start_dt_lteq[]`, does not work as intended

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following using array string `start_dt_lteq[]`

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'start_dt_lteq[]', (date.to_date + 7.days), input_html: { name: 'week-#{i}' } %>
```

it will take all checked box value. If you use this `:start_dt_lteq` it will take only last value.

Comment: Updated my question to reflect the results of this suggestion.